# How to solve Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('url', function (data) {
        console.log("Before:"+data);
        t = data;
        console.log("After:"+t);
    });
</script>
```

When I am using `getJson` method to get data from REST API , I am getting the error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at the url. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

How do I solve this? Please help.

Comment: *"by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS"* or, if the service supports jsonp, using jsonp.

Comment: What it means moving the resource to same domain or how to enable CORS ?

Comment: it means exactly what that text says... i'm not sure how to put it simpler. Move your service (the resource) to the same domain (your webserver) or enable CORS (which is a process in which a cross origin request is made. research it.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is provided by the error message

Comment: yes answer is provided. if u can explain what it means.

Comment: Solve it, by moving the service from the remote server to your server, or by making a CORS request. Or, by using JSONP instead (which is not ajax)

Comment: Is your first argument to `$.getJSON()` really the string *"url"*?

Comment: No, I mean the **literal string** *"url"*. Because that's what you've got in your code and unless your service endpoint is `./url` (which it isn't because that wouldn't throw a cross-origin error), you're not giving us the full picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at the url. This can be fixed by moving the
>   resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

It means you should have api (`url` in your code) and the file which has your script must be in same domain

Or

Add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header` in the API(`url` in your code) domain

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

`*` to allow all cross domainrequests

Comment: We don't know it's PHP or even if it was, whether or not the resource ends in `.php` so I'd just stop making assumptions because they're only going to confuse OP

Comment: You don't say what server that code for.  Is it Apache?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I added this to my httpd-vhosts.conf and the error was solved

Comment: Isn't this answer exactly the same as the earlier one?