# Nginx: Proxy turn requests

Tags: javascript, nginx, proxy, turn

I am hosting my own TURN-Server and I have configured NGINX as my web server.

This is my problem:

I have a JavaScript WebRTC client which needs to call a turn server for ICE Candidates, so my TURN-Server is running on the 40501 port.

Unfortunately in JavaScript I am getting the Cross Origin Request Blocked error!

Here's where NGINX is called for help. I configured NGINX to listen on the port 40500 and proxy the requests to the port 40501 on which my TURN-Server is running as follows:

```
upstream turn{
        server 128.199.xx.xx:40501;
}
server {
            listen       40500;
            server_name  _;
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://turn;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                    return 204;
                }
                if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                }
                if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                }
            }
        }
```

But it did no good to me. I cannot connect to my TURN-Sever through NGINX. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051759/how-to-solve-cross-origin-request-blocked-error-in-firefox

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @AbdulBasit No sir. That project was discontinued due to a lot of issues and lack of sources